# How Spring Security add/configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am working on Spring Security Java-based configuration.

I have created my own `MyAuthenticationProvider` which I want to register in the `ProviderManager` (single instance of `AuthenticationManager`).

I have found that `ProviderManager` has a list of providers to which I can register my single 
`MyAuthenticationProvider`.

Here is the part of my Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(MyAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

I found out that `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` has `parentAuthenticationManager`, `defaultUserDetailsService` and many other fields.

My questions are:

1. Where is this `@Autowired` annotation adding `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` auth from? 
   Is the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` already created in the application context?
2. What would be the default state of `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` which is being        injected? By default state I mean will there be some `parentAuthenticationManager`, `authenticationProvider`s already registered in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`?
3. If I am adding `auth.authenticationProvider(MyAuthenticationProvider)`, does this mean that I am adding one more provider in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`?
4. What does this mean? Taken from Spring Documentation

   > The name of the configureGlobal method is not important. However, it
   >   is important to only configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder in a class
   >   annotated with either @EnableWebSecurity, @EnableWebMvcSecurity,
   >   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, or @EnableGlobalAuthentication. Doing
   >   otherwise has unpredictable results.

Answer (score 15):

### Answer for 1:

`@EnableWebSecurity` is meta-annotated with `@EnableGlobalAuthentication`

```
...
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@Configuration
public @interface EnableWebSecurity {
...
```

and `@EnableGlobalAuthentication` imports `AuthenticationConfiguration`:

```
...
@Import(AuthenticationConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public @interface EnableGlobalAuthentication {
}
```

In `AuthenticationConfiguration`, you'll see that an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean is declared:

```
...
@Bean
public AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder(
        ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor, ApplicationContext context) {
    ...
}
```

When you `@Autowire` an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, this is the one that you will get. You have several methods at your disposal to easily configure in-memory, jdbc, ldap,... authentication.

### Answer for 2:

**Background:**

The Spring Security Java config goes through several stages to seamlessly incorporate your configurations with the `ApplicationContext`.One place where this comes together is in the `getHttp()` method in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

For example, this is an excerpt:

```
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManager();

authenticationBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
```

To give you an idea of how "not-straightforward" the sequence of configuration is, the authenticationManager variable above will be either:

- The authentication manager you added by overriding `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`
- OR: The authentication manager you added in the method that `@Autowired` the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean from AuthenticationConfiguration
- OR: an AuthenticationManager bean found in the context

> By default state I mean will there be some [...] authenticationProviders already registered in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

If you look at `AuthenticationConfiguration`, you'll see that by default, the `InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer` is applied to the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean. As long as it finds a `UserDetailsService` bean in the context and no other provider has been added, it will add a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. This is why in the [Spring Security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration), only providing a @Bean `UserDetailsService` bean is sufficient.

But once you add an authentication provider as you did, the "default" provider is not registered.

Comment: may i know how you can answer this deep question ? are you using specific IDE feature or any keyword on google ?

i like the way you explain @NatFar

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, brute force - going through the Spring Security source code on their github repo :)

Answer (score 5):

Answer for 3:

Yes. The code of AuthenticationManagerBuilder adds your provider:

```
public AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
    this.authenticationProviders.add(authenticationProvider);
    return this;
}
```

---

Answer for 4 is simple:

It means that, once you have one of that annotations, you can name your method as you wish:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity  //or @EnableWebMvcSecurity or @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity....
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void myCoolMethodName(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(MyAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

> "Doing otherwise has unpredictable results"

If you keep the name but not the annotations, it may not work.

Comment: Btw, you don't have to annotate class with `@Configuration` if it has `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation

Comment: What to do if I am not using `BCryptPasswordEncoder`? I am using `SHA3.Digest256` with salt and I am not sure how to set this on the AuthenticationManager.