# How to find the location of a spring bean registration from a stack trace?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring for the first time and having trouble following the code. When reading code without spring I can easily find the source code that led to an object being created by setting a breakpoint and looking at the call stack.  With spring the call stack (e.g. like the one below) shows the object being instantiated by the framework, but there's not much resemblance to the original code.  Looking at the parent methods I can see the constructor that requires the child bean to be created, but whats the best way to find where the child bean was registered in the first place?

In the stacktrace below I was trying to find what declared AuthenticationManagerBuilder as a bean. [How Spring Security add/configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948090/how-spring-security-add-configure-authenticationmanagerbuilder) gives the answer to that question. How could I have figured that out starting with the stack trace?

````
<init>:67, AuthenticationManagerBuilder (org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders)
authenticationManagerBuilder:72, AuthenticationConfiguration (org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration)
CGLIB$authenticationManagerBuilder$2:-1, AuthenticationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d89cebe3 (org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration)
invoke:-1, AuthenticationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d89cebe3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$831c0ad8 (org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration)
invokeSuper:228, MethodProxy (org.springframework.cglib.proxy)
intercept:358, ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor (org.springframework.context.annotation)
authenticationManagerBuilder:-1, AuthenticationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d89cebe3 (org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:62, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:498, Method (java.lang.reflect)
instantiate:162, SimpleInstantiationStrategy (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
instantiateUsingFactoryMethod:588, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
instantiateUsingFactoryMethod:1173, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBeanInstance:1067, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:513, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support) [5]
createBean:483, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:306, AbstractBeanFactory$1 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:230, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:302, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:202, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveCandidate:208, DependencyDescriptor (org.springframework.beans.factory.config)
doResolveDependency:1138, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveDependency:1066, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveAutowiredArgument:835, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createArgumentArray:741, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
autowireConstructor:189, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
autowireConstructor:1193, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBeanInstance:1095, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:513, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support) [4]
createBean:483, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:306, AbstractBeanFactory$1 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:230, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:302, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:197, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
instantiateUsingFactoryMethod:372, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
instantiateUsingFactoryMethod:1173, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBeanInstance:1067, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:513, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support) [3]
createBean:483, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:306, AbstractBeanFactory$1 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:230, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:302, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:202, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveCandidate:208, DependencyDescriptor (org.springframework.beans.factory.config)
doResolveDependency:1138, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveDependency:1066, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveAutowiredArgument:835, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createArgumentArray:741, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
autowireConstructor:189, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
autowireConstructor:1193, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBeanInstance:1095, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:513, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support) [2]
createBean:483, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:306, AbstractBeanFactory$1 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:230, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:302, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:202, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveCandidate:208, DependencyDescriptor (org.springframework.beans.factory.config)
doResolveDependency:1138, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveDependency:1066, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
resolveAutowiredArgument:835, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createArgumentArray:741, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
autowireConstructor:189, ConstructorResolver (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
autowireConstructor:1193, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBeanInstance:1095, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:513, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support) [1]
createBean:483, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:306, AbstractBeanFactory$1 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:230, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:302, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:197, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
preInstantiateSingletons:761, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
finishBeanFactoryInitialization:867, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:543, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:122, EmbeddedWebApplicationContext (org.springframework.boot.context.embedded)
refresh:693, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
refreshContext:360, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:303, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:1118, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:1107, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
main:95, MyApplication (myapp)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:62, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
invoke:498, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:49, RestartLauncher (org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart)```
````

Comment: Could you add your code?  That might help a bit more.

Comment: Not really, this is a general problem I have with any spring code.